# How to treat the response from an xmlhttprequest as a DOM object?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

How can I treat the response from an xmlhttprequest as a DOM object and parse it using methods such as `getElementsByTagName()`?  I don't control the page I am parsing and am doing this within the context of a content.js for a chrome extension.

I have this:

```
//prior to this there is a typical xmlhttprequest, which works fine
var webpage = xmlhttp.responseText;

//this returns an error: webpage.getElementsByTagName is not a function
//I've tried xmlhttp.responseText as well as xmlhttp.response
var elements = webpage.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

I appreciate there is a similar question here [How to create DOM object from html page received over XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972880/how-to-create-dom-object-from-html-page-received-over-xmlhttprequest), however

1. I can't get the answer to that to work (tried it using an iframe),
2. not sure if it is the solution for a whole webpage (html tags and all) as well as for a chrome extension.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and simply set responseType to `'document'` or use DOMParser API.

Comment: [Parsing XMLHttpRequest() result (using XPath)](//stackoverflow.com/a/40750779)

Comment: @wOxxOm groan, right got it.  I did spot that `xmlhttp.response` was supposed to return a document but didn't get that you needed to explicitly tell it using `xmlhttp.responseType`.  Many thanks - if you shift your comment down to an answer I'll mark it as correct.